# htaccess redirection issue in local server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I am trying to run my project in local server (WAMP), it is redirecting to www.localhost.com

When I type localhost/MYPROJECTNAME then it is redirecting to www.localhost.com

Please find below code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /MYPROJECTNAME
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: That's because you're adding `www` in the last rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it shouldn't redirect if it's localhost.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /MYPROJECTNAME
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Negate for `localhost` and more importantly change the order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /MYPROJECTNAME/

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.|localhost) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```